# Linking domain to vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, hosts, puphpet

This may be a simple question, but I've done a fair bit of googling/watching tutorial videos and I have no idea why this is failing.

### Background

I have a codebase that I'm going to be working on with rest of my dev team. Everyone is using different setups. They have dev servers to roll out to, but they are also not particularly well maintained and do have slightly different installs. The next project I start also requires a php upgrade, so I thought to use vagrant to allow a uniform testing environment (amongst other reasons).

Using puphpet seems logical and has served me well before.

### The problem

While setting up the box I configured puphpet as expected. The commant `vagrant up` also works as expected. I can SSH in as required.

I can also access the server via it's configured ip (`192.168.56.101`). If I do, I get the standard message:

Congratulations! You are pretty awesome.
[blah blah]

However, if you are seeing this page, it means you are using IP Address, not virtual host!

So - I then opened my (windows) host and added the following:

`192.168.56.101       iccell.local`

When I then navigate to `http://iccell.local` I get caught by some search engine and end up at `http://searchguide.level3.com/search/?q=http%3A//iccell.local/&r=&t=0`

The hosts entry doesn't seem to be correct, but I have no idea why.
Can any body suggest how to fix it/why that would be the case/point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: using chrome or IE ? I guess IE should work as it uses the windows host file, not sure chrome does

Comment: All browsers were the issue

Answer (score 0):

As I posted this, I looked for other possible explanations.

I found a very informative post on SO's sister site; Server Fault.

https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

In my case, for some reason, my hosts file had been saved in a non standard encoding. I fixed this, replacing tabs/space and adding a blank line. I then flushed DNS and things seemed to be fixed.

I'm answering here as a tool to point to the above answer. It's in depth and very informative.